# Equivalente al estilo will-change usando la API experimental de JavaScript Web Animations API

Tags: javascript, css3, api

he estado leyendo la documentación de la API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API) y he estado buscando formas de usar el equivalente al estilo will-change (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change) para mejorar el rendimiento de las animaciones. Sé que este estilo se debe utilizar con mucho cuidado pero me sorprende que no consiga encontrar un equivalente en esta API.

Mi pregunta es ¿existe alguna forma de sugerir al navegador qué optimizaciones debe realizar de forma parecida a will-change en animaciones CSS o a lo más que puedo aspirar es a añadir un desplazamiento nulo con una transformación 3D para forzar que la animación sea procesada por la tarjeta gráfica?

Comment: ¿Puedo saber el motivo de los votos negativos? Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Puedo suponer que los votos negativos, son porque se trata de una petición para opiniones. ¿Has intentado esta misma pregunta en el **chat**?

Comment: Buenos días @EdgarGutiérrez :), en realidad no estoy solicitando ninguna opinión, sino pregunto si existe o no una forma de hacer lo que quiero hacer. Si existe o no un equivalente a will-change en una animación generada por esta API. Me interesa tu opinión, ¿qué es lo que podría hacer que un usuario pensara que estoy pidiendo una opinión? Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Con respecto al chat, no lo he intentado. Ahora en España es bastante tarde para quienes tenemos que madrugar, pero es una muy buena idea, lo intentaré mañana

Comment: Hola @EdgarGutiérrez, al final encontré la solución en un artículo de CSS-Tricks :)

Answer (score 0):

Al final, tras mucho buscar he encontrado que la API no contempla un equivalente a will-change porque se aspira a poder trabajar sin él. Cualquier desarrollador que quiera usar will-change y la WAAPI tendrá que aplicar este estilo a los elementos que desee animar.

Animo a cualquiera que tenga interés en esta API a leer este artículo en CSS-Tricks (en inglés):

https://css-tricks.com/css-animations-vs-web-animations-api/

En especial, la sección de rendimiento:

https://css-tricks.com/css-animations-vs-web-animations-api/#article-header-id-5

Es muy interesante la siguiente parte (traducción libre, en el contexto de las animaciones basadas en la WAAPI):

"Si usted tiene un retraso en su animación, no debería plantearse utilizar will-change. El autor principal de la especificación ha publicado un consejo interesante en la comunidad de los animadores de Slack. No creo que le importe que lo repita aquí:

Si su animación tiene un retraso positivo no se debe molestar en usar will-change debido a que el navegador web creará capas al inicio del retraso de tal forma que cuando la animación comience estará lista para funcionar"

(Fin de la traducción)

Espero que sirva a todos los que tuvieran la misma duda.